# What does “INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 84% if used)” actualy mean?

Tags: centos, centos7, cron

What does the following log line mean?

```
INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 84% if used.)
```

Googling didn't find meaningful answers: is the answer only in the sources?

(OS is CentOS 7)

**Edit**

This line was received from `logwatch`, viz:

```
 ################### Logwatch 7.4.0 (03/01/11) ####################
        Processing Initiated: Wed Jul 15 09:38:02 2020
        Date Range Processed: yesterday
                              ( 2020-Jul-14 )
                              Period is day.
        Detail Level of Output: 0
        Type of Output/Format: mail / text
        Logfiles for Host: laptop.local
 ##################################################################

 --------------------- Cron Begin ------------------------

 **Unmatched Entries**
 INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 84% if used.)
 INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 47% if used.)
 INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 74% if used.)
 INFO (Shutting down)
 INFO (RANDOM_DELAY will be scaled with factor 23% if used.)

 ---------------------- Cron End -------------------------
```

The actual log, where these lines come from, was `/var/log/cron`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crontab(5) man page gives the answer:

> ```
>    The RANDOM_DELAY variable allows delaying job startups by random
>    amount of minutes with upper limit specified by the variable. The
>    random scaling factor is determined during the cron daemon startup so
>    it remains constant for the whole run time of the daemon.
> ```

So if you put `RANDOM_DELAY=60` in your crontab, the actual delay before the job starts will be the logged percentage, e.g. 84% of 60 minutes. Nothing happens if you don't use `RANDOM_DELAY`.